# Iterar sobre numeros reales + incremento en python 3.6

Tags: python

Hola necesito calcular el metodo de tanteos en python 3.6 y para ello necesito rrecorrer con un for pero mi traba es que segun entiendo, el for en python no acepta floats como rango en la funcion range().¿que otra forma habria de hacerlo?
paso lo que tengo hasta ahora asì se entiende mejor.

```
from sympy import *
from numpy import *

a = float(input('ingrese el valor de a'))
inc = float(input('ingrese el incremento'))
b = float(input('ingrese el valor de b'))


for i in range(a,b,inc):
    print(a+inc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Efecivamente `range()` genera sólo números enteros. Aunque usando `numpy` tendrías `arange()` que sí admite floats, en realidad no lo necesitas. Basta que cambies tu `for` por un `while`, con algo como esto:

```
i = a
while i<b:
   print(i)
   i+=inc
```

Como he dicho, también puedes usar `numpy.arange()`, así:

```
for i in arange(a, b, inc):
    print(i)
```

pero numpy generará un array con todos los números entre `a` y `b` (separados a intervalos `inc`), y será sobre ese array sobre el que iterará el `for`. Si no necesitas tal array sino sólo iterar por los números, puedes ahorrarte el uso de memoria que ese array supondría (especialmente si es muy grande), usando la técnica del `while` antes vista.